# On Click Error: "occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the OLE Server or ActiveX Control"

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Seems like this is has been asked a few times before.

After working on a form for a few weeks, I suddenly get the error when I click on a button:  "The expression On Click you entered as the event property produced the following error:  A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the OLE Server or Active X Control."

This also happens with any control's event on the form (e.g. After Update on other text fields)

I tried re-installing Access to no avail.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I have a subform on the form as well.  I have an "on-click" event that works on the subform, but when the code breaks at the following line (which worked before):

```
Me.Parent.orderID = Null
```

The error I get is:  "Method 'Parent' of object '_Form_frmOrderQuery' failed
(frmOrderQuery is the name of the subform)

Anyway, this all worked before until I changed the query for the subform by adding a few more fields.

Finally:  All of the event handlers (button click, after-update, etc) work on my other forms in the database.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

jeff

Answer (score 12):

Figured it out, this was stupid easy. Whatever Form is having issues, just copy it and delete the old form. Rename the new form to the same as the last (so all your vba and stuff works). Done!

Comment: I've been researching this issue, for the past hour, except my error said "a problem occurred while x was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control". This fixed it

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Simple as that, Only replaced the form for its copy and the problem was gone! Thanks

Comment: Just had to say thank you for this. This really helped me out today.

Answer (score 2):

As other users mentioned the problem is in use of non-English symbols in element (form control, etc.) names.
My way to solve it:

1. (may be unnecessary) Create an event procedure for any element on a form.
2. Switch to Code Editor.
3. Place cursor inside any procedure.
4. Open drop-down list with element names (the left one above the code window).
5. Check if you see some names with "?????" in them.
6. If 5 is true, then figure out what the elements are, find them on the form and rename using only  basic latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into a similar problem using the Access runtime environment. It seems that the problem might be with... non-Unicode lanuage settings.

Maybe the names of the columns you added to the query contain some problematic characters?

See this article for reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907337. It contains a resolution, which helped me.

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue occured because of accented characters.

I was running the VBA code on a computer that uses *different non-Unicode language settings than the computer on which i created* the event handler, the function, or the subroutine. Note This issue may also occur if the VBA code contains accented characters or special characters. Additionally, this issue may occur if an object name in the Access database contains accented characters or special characters.

**The Solution that worked for me:**

> If you are running the VBA code on a Microsoft Windows XP-based computer or on a Windows 2000-based computer, you may be able to resolve this issue by changing the non-Unicode language setting on the computer where you are running the VBA code. To verify and to change the non-Unicode language setting, follow these steps.
>
> Note Because there are several versions of Microsoft Windows, the following steps may be different on your computer. If they are, see your product documentation to complete these steps.
>
> Click Start,  click Run,  type Intl.cpl, and then click OK.
>
> Under Language for non-Unicode programs on the Advanced tab, verify
> that the language matches the language on the computer on which you
> created the event handler, the function, or the subroutine. If the
> language differs, click the language that you want, and then click OK.
> Restart the computer.

From https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/907337